# Putting the result of the longitude and latitude in a EditText

Tags: android

I just want to ask on how to change the TOAST to an EditText in my code in getting the location. Or how to get the result of the longitude at latitude and place it in EditText or a TextView. here's my codes., just ignore the cam request.

Sorry for my bad English.

```
    package com.example.rifrancisco.hello;


    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnShowLocation;
    GPSTracker gps;

    Button btn_Transfer;

    Button btnTakePhoto;
    ImageView imgTakePhoto;

    private static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1313;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OnClickButtonListener();

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

                if(gps.canGetLocation()){
                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                 Toast.makeText(
                          getApplicationContext(),
                           "your Location is -\nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: "
                                    + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }

        });

        btnTakePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PhotoCap);
        imgTakePhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);

        btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(new btnTakePhotoClicker());


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        //TODO Auto Generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        Button generate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button3);
        Button cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);


        if(requestCode == CAM_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imgTakePhoto.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            generate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//To set visible
        }

    }


    public void OnClickButtonListener(){
        btn_Transfer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button3);
        btn_Transfer.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.rifrancisco.hello.PhotoInformationActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }
        );

        btn_Transfer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ViewData);
        btn_Transfer.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.rifrancisco.hello.ViewData");
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }
        );

    }




    class btnTakePhotoClicker implements Button.OnClickListener

    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto generated method stub
            Intent cameraintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraintent, CAM_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid asking solutions for you particular code. S.O. is more about a solution for a problem anyone could have. If yours fit in that category, explain(editing) better your case instead of asking someone to look and try to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
OnClickButtonListener();

btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
edtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edittext1);
btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

        if(gps.canGetLocation()){
            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

      edtext="your Location is -\nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: "
                            + longitude;
         Toast.makeText(
                  getApplicationContext(),
                   "your Location is -\nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: "
                            + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
    }

});

btnTakePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PhotoCap);
imgTakePhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);

btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(new btnTakePhotoClicker());
```

}

Comment: When posting answers, always explain why the code you provided is the appropriate answer. Never just give code and don't explain it. An explanation helps other people who may have a similar problem later.

Answer (score 0):

Add one EditText (let's say you declare in your java code as etLatLng)

```
EditText etLatLng = findViewById(R.id.WhateverIdYouPutInXML)
```

and then replace this code you have:

```
Toast.makeText(
getApplicationContext(),
"your Location is -\nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: "
+ longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to this:

```
etLatLng.setText("your Location is -\nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: "
+ longitude);
```

hope this helps.